# Xamarin.forms app crashes on inserting data to SQLite database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to take information entered by the user in the AddPage.Xaml.cs and add it to a SQLite database. The code runs fine until I press the add button then it crashes, I can't really figure out what is going on and I don't really know what I'm doing.

here is the necessary code and their corresponding classes.

This is in the AddPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task AddButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.characterDatabase.SaveCharacter(new Character()
    {
        Name = NameTxt.Text,
        Species = SpeciesTxt.Text,
        ImageUrl = ImageUrlTxt.Text
    });
}
```

The CharacterDatabaseController.cs

```
public class CharacterDatabaseController
{

    static object locker = new object();

    SQLiteConnection database;

    public CharacterDatabaseController()
    {
        database = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().DbConnection();
        database.CreateTable<Character>();
    }

    public Character GetCharacter()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (database.Table<Character>().Count() == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return database.Table<Character>().First();
            }
        }
    }

    public int SaveCharacter(Character character)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (character.Id != 0)
            {
                database.Update(character);
                return character.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                return database.Insert(character);
            }
        }
    }

    public int DeleteCharacter(int id)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return database.Delete<Character>(id);
        }
    }
}
```

and the App.cs:

```
public static CharacterDatabaseController characterDatabase
{
    get
    {
        if (characterDatabase == null)
        {
            CharacterDatabase = new CharacterDatabaseController();
        }
        return CharacterDatabase;
    }
}
```

Comment: use the debugger, or add some try/catch blocks, to identity which specific line is causing the crash and what the Exception is

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? You need to provide more information so we can help.